# Minecraft huge deep holes

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play on a Xbox One X and my Minecraft survival world I have been playing for about 2 months and a hour a day. And then all of a sudden, these huge deep holes appear and i have no idea why. There is a similar question about the issue  and I have tried all the things people said would work. I have gone to the nether, logged out and logged back in, saved and quit and also made a copy of the world. With the hole I can jump down and I fall into the void bellow killing myself in a matter of seconds. I would really appreciate it if someone could help because I have made a lot of advancements and also have been incredibly lucky with this.
[image]

This is not my world but this is what happened and there are many of them where my house and everything else resigns.

Comment: Is this the missing chunk glitch? I think you may need to reset the game, or update your game to a better, newer version. You should try that.

Comment: The difference to my problem is that you can fall in it and other people can see it. i have tried to go to that page @Joachim but most of them are for java eddition

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a missing chunk error/your hard drive is almost full/you selected "Old" as world type. If you look up what I'm saying on Google (or your preferred search engine) you'll find in-depth explanations.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I wasn't intending to respond, sorry for making it look like a comment response.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your answer.

Comment: @Winfinity I do not think my world is an "old" world because I only made 2 months ago. After the neather update and there has been no further updates. But thank you for you answer im glad people are helping me.

Comment: @Shrocler There is an "Old" world setting in MCBE (during world creation). Check it mid-game or when you edit your world.

Then again it could be a chunk error.

Comment: @Winfinity thank you i will try that :)